# Scoreboard checking in Minecraft

Tags: minecraft-commands

Is there a way for someone to check the scoreboard for every certain amount of numbers, so for example, if the score was 100 how would I check for the next 100 after, like 200.. 300.. 400 ect, or would they all need to be separately checked.

Comment: Which edition of Minecraft are you playing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create another objective which you will use for comparing the values and assign a starting value to this new objective. I will be using an objective named "temp":

```
/scoreboard players set global temp 100
```

I am also using a fake player called "global" to make the value more accessible.

Once your original objective reaches 100, you can execute something if you want to:

```
/execute if score global temp = <original_obj_holder> <original_obj> run say scores match
```

and then you have to increase the value of the temp objective by 100:

```
/execute if score global temp = <original_obj_holder> <original_obj> run scoreboard players add global temp 100
```

Comment: I actually used a different method to solve my problem but this also works, thank you for the help